# How to detect read errors in FileCopying in java?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, file-copying

Iam new to Java. I tried to do a file copier application using the basic `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` and `bufferedInputStream` and `bufferedOutputStream`. I used a Progress bar to show the Progress and it Worked. Everything was fine. I added the catch clause `FileNotFoundException` to report the error. Similarly when I tried to copy a file from a corrupted disk it copied upto some extent and stood still. How do I detect the `read errors`. Is there any catch clause? Please help me.

Comment: Is there any exception thrown at run-time?

Comment: There is an `IOException` that should be thrown if one of the IO operations fails. Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html for how `IOExceptions` work.

Comment: No. It stood still for half an hour

Answer (score 2):

There's no real solution to this.  Java relies on the operating system to do low-level file I/O.  If the operating system decides to freeze for a long time while it retries to read a corrupt file, there's nothing that the Java application can do about it.

> How do I detect the read errors. Is there any catch clause?

If / when the `read` operation eventually fails, you will get an IOException of some kind.  But adding a catch for the exception would not do anything to unblock the stalled read request.

Recovering data from corrupted disks is not the sort of thing you should try do in Java.  You need to write a native application that can access the disk device at the disk block level.  Or better, use an existing data recovery tool.

Comment: I am not trying to Recover data. I just want to report the Read Error in a message Box.

Comment: If you've got a known corrupted disc, you shouldn't be **attempting** to read it.  But like I said, there is no good solution.  The best you could do would be to create a watchdog thread that watched for the thread doing the read not making progress.  But once it detects that, there's nothing it can do to recover.

Comment: @SuhailAhamed - my last comment pretty much answers that.   When the watchdog thread detects that the copier thread is stuck, it should report the problem to the user and then cause the entire application to exit.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your `read()` and `write()` statements on your `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` objects (resp.), an `IOException` may arise from the native part if there's a problem in reading or writing from / into the file system. You can catch it the same way you caught the `FileNotFoundException`, and see its message to have more information on the specific error.